As a graduate student, should I tell my advisor that I am neurodivergent?
I'll be finishing my MSc in the next 4-5 months and plan to apply for PhD programs. I’m concerned, though, that my advisor might mention communication issues in his letter of recommendation.
To explain a bit more, I had some difficulties communicating with him while working on my MSc thesis, especially around choosing the thesis topic. I put a lot of effort into improving our communication, but I suspect he may still bring this up.
This partly stems from being neurodivergent, which can make it challenging for me to actively listen and maintain focus at times—a trait he’s pointed out to me several times. I’m uncertain whether I should share this underlying reason with him or keep it to myself. I worry that if I disclose my neurodivergence, it might make advisors, or even him, hesitant to consider me for a PhD position.

ASD and ADHD are common in academia, I don't have numbers to support the incidence being higher than in the general population. That said, I do think there is a question on this somewhere ...

There is this one, which is a close match, and more recently this one about disclosing to one's students.

When you label yourself as "neurodivergent", does that mean that you have some sort of diagnosis (which I am not at all asking you to disclose here) or that you have simply chosen to self-identify with that label? If you have an actual diagnosis of some sort (such as ADHD), I would recommend using that instead of the nebulous label "neurodivergent" in your communication with your current and future advisors. On the other hand, if you don't have an actual diagnosis, I would recommend to omit mention of neurodivergence altogether.

@AdamPřenosil That's more of an answer than a comment.

Also if you have a diagnosis, and it affects your performance, you probably have to disclose it to any university you apply to. Failure to do so could lead to future dismissal from your program. Disclosure could lead to special treatment due to a disability.

@Dirk Not really. "Do you have a diagnosis?" is a clarifying question, not an answer.

@AzorAhai-him- The part after the question mark is basically a full answer.

@DavidSmith, that is not a totally reasonable suggestion. No (reasonable) university is going to formally dismiss you merely on the grounds that they have decided you have ADD and you "haven't mentioned it in your application". They might dismiss you because your ADD renders your studies difficult but that is a completely different issue.

@DavidSmith. People aren't required to disclose a disability. The purpose of disclosure is to help, not hurt the individual. Thus people with disabilities have agency over when, how, and whether they disclose their disability.

@Eggy At universities I am familiar with, students with disabilities were allowed accomodation in exams only if they divulged their disability to the university when they started their program. Moreover, faculty were not allowed to accomodate students who told only an instructor that they had a disability. Faculty had to follow university policies on what accomodations to make. In short, when and how to express agency was regulated by university policy.

@David Smith: My main point is that this is incorrect: "If you have a diagnosis, and it affects your performance, you probably have to disclose it to any university you apply to." Students are not required to disclose a disability.

Further, your statement that "Failure to [disclose a disability] could lead to future dismissal from your program" is also incorrect and a violation of the Americans with Disabilities Act in the U.S. Requiring people to disclose a disability when they apply to a school would tremendously disadvantage them in the admissions process.

The time to make this decision would have been at the beginning of your relationship, or at least in the first half of your studies. If you had said, for example, "I have some health issues that make it difficult to concentrate, so I'd like to schedule three 20-minute meetings rather than one hour-long meeting," that would have been a "reasonable accommodation" that he should have agreed to. (In fact, he may have been legally required to comply, though I hope it wouldn't come to that.) And then with this accommodation, you hopefully would have been able to meet his expectations, and he could give you a strong letter.
At this point, however, you have almost finished your degree, and so the die is largely cast. Just like the undergrad who has already taken the final exam, there is very little you can do to improve your situation at this point. All you can do is try to do a good job on any remaining work and then wait for the grade (letter) to come out.
So: you can tell him or not tell him; it is your private medical information that you can disclose as you see fit. But it should not make much difference either way; regardless of the reasons, your performance was what it was.  People being people, it may in practice make some small difference, but without knowing your advisor, I could not guess in which direction. The important thing is to apply "lessons learned" here to your future endeavors.

I suggest writing your thoughts in a separate answer, then.

Understanding the reason for your difficulty doesn’t by itself make it less of a constraint on your ability to communicate or focus effectively. If there are known accommodations or work-arounds that could make this less of a constraint in your future work, then it is worth disclosing the issue. Or if you think your advisor might have come to an alternative, mistaken and unflattering explanation for the issues you have had, then the true explanation could clear things up. If not — well, it doesn’t really matter what the cause of a limitation is or what label is put on that cause if it is still a limitation. And although neurodivergence is starting to be more widely recognised in academic environments, there is still a lot of misunderstanding so the labels can still come with some stigma. In short: I’d advise against disclosure unless there are clear steps that can be taken to help if people know about it, or unless you are so strongly affected that it will be obvious even if you don’t disclose.
(On the other hand, the more people do disclose neurodivergence or disabilities, the less stigma there will be in future).

I'm autistic and have ADHD, both of which I told my MSc supervisor about when I started working on my MSc thesis. I believe this led to him making an extra effort to be clear in his communication with me, and he also supported me by helping me plan my work in smaller chunks and having intermediate deadlines. If there are specific, actionable accommodations that you would like to request, and you believe that disclosing a disability would provide context for why you are making the request, then I think it is worth disclosing.
In general, I would not disclose to try and make people view past behaviour more positively, unless you can also point to something that has changed since and the steps you're taking to address it, as it is likely to just come across as making excuses.
You might want to say something like this: "I know we've had issues with miscommunication, and I've noticed a pattern of us coming away from meetings with different understandings of what we discussed. I've realised that this is due to [specific disability], and am working on strategies to improve this. I want to start taking notes during meetings, which might mean I need to pause to write during the meeting. I would also like to email you a summary after the meeting, which should hopefully make it clear if I have major misunderstandings of what we discussed."
You are acknowledging the problems, explaining the cause, and explaining the steps you will take to address it. This is the kind of conversations I've had with my supervisors about my disabilities. They have actually praised my communication skills recently, I think in part because I have acknowledged what the problems are and have taken steps to make sure we have a shared understanding of anything significant.

The decision about whether to now disclose a neurodivergence to your supervisor is a difficult one, but with 4-5 months still left to run on your MSc, it could be worth it. With 4-5 months left, there is still time to work more effectively with your supervisor for the write up of your MSc.
I disagree with answers that say "A limitaiton is a limitation irrepsective of what the reason for it is". For many factors associated with neurodivergence, there are ways in which things can be done differently to work with your neurotype, rather than against it. For example, people with ASD can often communicate very effectively if the forms of, and methods for, commuication are set up correctly, and the correct expectiations are set on both sides.
You will need to apply some judgement about how your supervisor might react - academics as a group are a forward thinking and accepting bunch, but obviously there are those that are less understanding. If you have a hard time judging this, you might need to ask help from someone you trust who also knows your supervisor somewhat.
Going forward, I think caution is less important - when choosing a PhD supervisor, anyone who reacts negatively so the information on your neurotype is not someone you wanted as your supervisor anyway.

In my answer, I said that the cause of a limitation doesn’t matter IF there aren’t any accommodations or work arounds that can help. Not that it doesn’t matter regardless.


I'll be finishing my MSc in the next 4-5 months and plan to apply for PhD programs. I’m concerned, though, that my advisor might mention communication issues in his letter of recommendation.

So you want him not to mention it, or just in a soft, or even in a positive way?
If so, what I would do is find the right opportunity to thank him for his efforts when communicating with you because you have XYZ (some common sense explanation of your problem).
You could have brought this earlier, to be honest, but you are where you are.
Not telling him means that he may put it in the letter, especially if he is annoyed by the issue.
Telling him means that he may think "ahhh, this is why..." and not put anything. Or think "they should have told me earlier, what a lack of professionalism" and highlight that you have a problem an do not manage it correctly.
It is really a matter of feeling and a gamble.
If it were me I would tell him.

Yes, it could be beneficial to share this with your advisor, especially if it impacts your work or communication style. Letting them know may help create a more understanding and supportive environment, allowing for any necessary accommodations. However, consider your advisor’s openness to such topics and only share if you feel comfortable.

It is always your choice whether or not to disclose a disability or neurodivergence (addendum: meaning that, within a disability rights framework, you should not feel compelled to disclose your neurodivergence unless you wish to). However, pragmatically speaking, your supervisor may have benefited from being informed that you have specific communication needs. If you feel comfortable doing so, you could try writing them an email to explain the situation and acknowledge that it may have been confusing or challenging for them, leading to unintended tensions in your working relationship. It is unclear from your question whether or not you believe an apology is appropriate in this situation, but it may be in your best interest to extend an olive branch at this time.
All of this being said, your university is very likely to have an office established for students with disabilities, neurodiversity, or other circumstances that require modifications for accessibility. Depending on the policy at your institution, you may or may not be required to provide evidence of a formal diagnosis. Before proceeding with your advisor, I think you should reach out to the relevant administration contact, because they potentially have an official policy or procedure for these types of situations. At my university, we (academic staff) are notified when students disclose a disability or difference that may affect how they learn and interact with us and their fellow students. Upon your disclosure, administration may directly inform your advisor, which could be easier and less awkward for all involved.

@user210544 - I'm not saying that this answer is good, but that's a bad characterization of the answer. You even write the main reason that it's bad twice in your comment: the fact that the answer says that what they do is their own decision, so it clearly is not saying that any action is needed at all. The answer also implies that an apology may be a good or a bad idea depending on what the asker thinks is appropriate, but points out that it might be pragmatically helpful even if the asker does not think it is.

So, yeah, a bad misreading of the answer. "Feel free to do whatever you want based on what you think is right, but bear in mind that acknowledging any difficulties for them may be practically useful" is not the same as saying "you need to apologize." There have been many times that I have apologized for communication difficulties that at least in part probably stemmed from neurodivergence on my part, and that has absolutely been pragmatically helpful (and sometimes, even, helped show empathy). There have been times I felt that  the other people were more responsible, too, of course.

@user210544 there isn’t a single route forward and their choice is going to depend on how crucial they believe their supervisor’s future support is going to be.
